# How to run a Junit Plugin Test using Ant from eclipse

Tags: ant, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, junit4

How can we run a junit plugin test using ant from eclipse, also from command prompt? I'm using Junit4.4.

Answer (score 1):

The `org.eclipse.test` plugin provides a `library.xml` file that contains ant tasks for running plugin tests both in UI (`ui-test` target) and headless (`core-test` target) modes. Example of invoking the task below, you'll need to provide a few properties to suite your own environment and check the `org.eclipse.test` plugin version:

```
<property name="library-file"
    value="${eclipse-home}/plugins/org.eclipse.test_3.2.0/library.xml" />
```

...

```
    <ant target="ui-test" antfile="${library-file}"
        dir="${eclipse-home}">
        <property name="data-dir" value="${workspace}" />
        <property name="plugin-name" value="${plugin-name}" />
        <property name="classname"
            value="com.example.MyTestSuite" />
        <property name="junit-report-output" value="${results.dir}"/>
    </ant>
```